Is there a way to get the real query generated by Uniface on a read trigger?
Background
I am updating Oracle logic that is called by Uniface 9.7.03. I am not expected to dive into the Uniface code, as I have no practical knowledge (beyond basic debugging) of the Uniface environment and it's a legacy system we don't want to touch.
Issue
I am done with my work on the Oracle side and see the data I'm supposed to. The matching Uniface screen however omits certain records.
My question
Can I generate or intercept the real query that Uniface uses to query the Oracle DB so I can compare that to my own?

This seem like a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database

It isn't, notice that this is about UNIFACE. Though that may be a way to catch it off system.

I tried that, it didn't catch the query.

gv$sql,gv$sqlarea,etc.. will all have your query. Be sure to search sql_fulltext and not sql_text which is just a snippet. If you have RAC, be sure to hit the gv$ views and not v$ views. You can also enable a 10046 trace and examine the trace file for the greatest precision, but that requires access to the database server (you'll need your DBA's help).
